# Use Python plotly chart in PHP

Tags: php, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have created a pie graph with Python plotly library

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=data["x"], values=data['value'])])
fig = dcc.Graph(id='pie_graph', figure=fig)
fig = fig.to_plotly_json()
```

And I want to depict this chart in a PHP page.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python /home/mypath/demo.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Since I am new to PHP, this approach returns a JSON with the characteristics of the chart and doesn't depict the chart.

I also tried

```
json_decode($output, TRUE)
```

But without success.

I know that plotly needs a layout to be depicted, but I don't know how to integrate it with the already implemented PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import plotly.io

print(plotly.io.to_html(fig))
```

(instead of fig = fig.to_plotly_json()). This will create a complete HTML document. For more details, see https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.to_html.html.